# How to write `app.yaml` file for Google App Engine app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

I registered a Google App Engine app and I have some files below:

- `/index.html`
- `/tabs.css`
- `/tab.js`
- `/temp.py`

How should I write the `app.yaml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put your static files into some directory, for example `staticdata`
then your app.yaml would look like:

```
application: temp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /staticdata
  static_dir: staticdata

- url: /.*
  script: temp.py
```