# how to deal with static files to write app.yaml?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to write yaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077336/how-to-write-yaml-file)

I registered a Google App Engine app and I have some files below:

/index.html

/tabs.css

/tab.js

/temp.py

How should I write the app.yaml file?

Comment: The polite way to bring attention to an old question is to post a bounty.

Comment: @sernold, I suggested malesh to change his old question or post a new one because the old title didn't reflect the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
application: ***your-app-name***
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/(.*)

- url: /public
  static_dir: public

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

Create a `pubic` directory under you app's root directory and put your static files in there.
You can include them in your HTML files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/style.css">
```